# iOS Copy Paste phone from contacts to UITextField adds strange unicode characters

Tags: ios, swift

The simplified scenario is the following.

- New project using Single View App template.
- Add a UITextField to the ViewController.
- Run the app and copy and paste a Contacts phone number [ej. John Appleseed one `(888) 555-5512)` ] to the UITextField.

The number will be added with a Unicode character at the beginning and at the end, getting like `\u{e2}(888) 555-5512\u{e2}` when exploring the variable while debugging.

This is really weird and in my opinion, not the intended behaviour.
Is this a bug or something that works intentionally this way?

**Code:**

Nothing complicated here. As described before, brand new project, add UITextField, add Button, and if button triggered print the result.
The print will show the phone just fine, just put a breakpoint in the `print` line and see the value of the phone var to see what I mean.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UITextField!

    @IBAction func goButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let text = phoneLabel.text ?? ""
        print(text)
    }
}
```

**Tested in:**

- iOS 11.1 - iPhone X
- Xcode 9.1

**Steps with images:**

[image]

---

[image]

---

This is what I got at the breakpoint line.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to duplicate it. I tried two phone numbers, one with an area code, one without. My copy/paste actions... (1) Click edit on the contact, (2) long press phone number and "select all", (3) copy, (4) long press target app, (5) "paste". EDIT: Also, I didn't do anything to the text field, just dragged one onto the storyboard - pretty much like you detailed. EDIT #2: My device was an iPad Mini 4 running iOS 11.2.

Comment: Same here, @dfd, can't reproduce the issue. iPad Pro 10.5'' Simulator on 11.1 w/ Xcode 9.1.

Comment: @dfd Yes, at a glance it seems to work just fine but in the debugger shows weird Unicode characters (see updated answer). There is no way you can't check this without seeing the actual value of the var while debugging. Print and plain UITextField text just look fine. If you don't want to debug try to delete the last character of the number and you will notice that you should delete 2 times (once for the Unicode and once for the actual number)

Comment: Update your question with relevant code. Where is this `text` variable coming from?

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. My guess is that this is "intended behavior". I used to work with Unicode alot. This looks like a low level kind of thing. UTF-8 prefixes special characters with "e2" (http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192). Many large "middleware" systems do various encoding behind the scenes. I guess the question for you is: Does it matter? (I mean beyond gaining an understanding.) If you copy/paste *into* this text field and then... copy/paste from it or programmatically send it to, say, Firebase, are things corrupted?

Comment: @rmaddy I have added sample code to add more context. Simple stuff.

Comment: @dfd Yes, things get weird with this characters if I don't add a "normalization" (clean all those characters) first. Characters count gets corrupted and even QA complains about why they need to touch the erase 2 times for deleting the last character (try by yourself) so that's why I think that this is not the intended behaviour.

Comment: Then I'll go with @rmaddy. You don't need to do anything twice inside a `UITextfield`. So what exactly *is* `text`? Maybe the code is looking at "raw" text when it shouldn't be?

Comment: @dfd I update the answer with some simple code. Is basic stuff. On top of my mind what if I want to add some validation to that text to activate a button if the phone is valid (let's say 6 digits) it won't work because the count won't say 6. Maybe I should deal with it and that's it, but this sounds like an OS bug or something.

Comment: I just added a button to my simple project. All it does is print the character count. Works fine - had answers of 0, 8, and 14. `print(textfield.text?.count)`. I'll bet if you pull the text out differently you'll fix your issue. So yes, please post some code. Thanks!

Comment: @dfd The issue is related to copy and pasting phone numbers from iOS Contacts into a Label. Have you tried copy and pasting and then count? Have tried right now copy-pasting several phones and always is the "real" amount of characters + 2 (the Unicode ones)

Comment: Well, to begin with, your title specifically says `UITextField`. :-) Personally, I'd never consider copy/paste into a `UILabel`, as that's not how things are "normally" done.

Comment: @dfd I was referring to a `UITextField` sorry, was a typo in my previous comment.

Comment: Then my previous comment stands. Contacts >> UITextField >> Print count works fine. Swift 4, Xcode 9.2 beta, iOS 11.2, everything else is default. I put my code out there on GitHub. If you find what I'm doing differently, let me know. (Ignore the garish background!) https://github.com/justdfd/testUnicode.git

Comment: Note: these annoying characters can also crop up when pasting from the Windows 10 Calculator: https://superuser.com/questions/1361155/how-to-stop-windows-10-calculator-from-enclosing-copied-text-in-202d-and-202c-un

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue recently. Interestingly enough what you see in the debugger is unfortunately not what is actually pasted.
If you copy the number to a different place and investigate it with your console for example you will get the following output:

```
>>> u"\U+202D(888) 5555-5512\U+202C"
u'\u202d(888) 5555-5512\u202c'
>>> name(u"\U+202D")
'LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE'
>>> name(u"\U+202C")
'POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING'
```

So as you can see it is really two different invisible characters controlling the flow of the text.

In order to solve that I filtered out all unicode characters of the `cF` [category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cf/list.htm). So you could do:

```
phoneLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\p{Cf}", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: @limfinityThis absolute does the magic. What a weird behaviour. Thanks for answering.

Comment: BTW, there is online converters to see unicode codes of chars (including hidden) in string. For example: https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

Comment: Thank you, we were having the same issue for years with mac users. What an awful thing, almost as evil a the non-breaking space :)