# Swift switch char{ case "\u{e2}:

Tags: swift, string, uitextview

```
let splitLines = line.split(separator: "\u{e2}")

case "\u{e2}":
                print("FoundBadReturn")

let newText = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{e2}", with: "\n")
```

I'm working with a RTF Document in UITextView.
I'm trying to change Strings that contain \u{e2} char with \n
None of these lines seem to work against Strings

Comment: Define doesn't work. Note that `\u{e2}`  it is the same as `â`

Comment: A String that has a "\u{e2}" does not split with the split function.

Comment: It does not replace with the replacing Occurrences function

Comment: And if you test it like this

Comment: if char == "\u{e2}"{
                newText.append("\n")
            } else {
                newText.append(char)
            }
            It don't work.

Comment: explain precisely what you have and what you want to have

Comment: line String "122871221621 \u{e2}Erica Lynn Jordan"

Comment: Example of a line that won't split above.

Comment: \u{e2} is a alternative of \n in a document that comes from word.

Comment: I first split the document on \n this gives me an array of lines. Unfortunately some of these lines have this char in them.  I want to split the lines on that character.  I've tried looping through the line testing for the character.  Using the split function on the character. Using a switch/case test on the character and using the replacingOcurrances function on the character.  None of these methods work.

Answer (score 5):

The debugger print is misleading. The character is `"\u{2028}"` 'Line Separator' rather than `"\u{e2}"`. The debugger does this because `0xE2` is the first byte of that character in UTF8, and it hides the rest. If you instead try to perform your operations (delete, replace, contains...) on `"\u{2028}"`, they will work.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the solution here? It works for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47835062/

```
phoneLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\p{Cf}", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: When copy phone number from `Phone` app, debuger show `\u{e2}`, but the real is: `\\p{Cf}` :))

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following function to solve this problem. It's probably not the best solution.

```
func splitOnAlternateNewline(line: String) -> [String]{
    var returnArray: [String] = []
    var aString = ""
    outLoop :for char in line{
        let aChar = String(char).utf16
        for a in aChar{
            if a == 8232{
                returnArray.append(aString)
                aString = ""
                continue outLoop

            }

        }
        aString.append(char)


    }
    returnArray.append(aString)
    return returnArray

}
```

Comment: 8232 is indeed the decimal value of 0x2028.