# How to remove special character \u{e2} from string

Tags: ios, swift

I have following code  in `func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool`

```
var phoneNumber: String?
if let callIntent = interaction.intent as? INStartVideoCallIntent {
    phoneNumber = callIntent.contacts?.first?.personHandle?.value
} else if let callIntent = interaction.intent as? INStartAudioCallIntent {
     phoneNumber = callIntent.contacts?.first?.personHandle?.value
}
```

Phone number has only 10 digit. But when I check the count it shows 12 Digits

[image]

When I print the string

[image]

I have tried

`phoneNumber?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).count`
`phoneNumber?.trimmingCharacters(in: .symbols).count`

but it still returns 12

Please help

Comment: @Scriptable No accepted answer  !! Could you please help

Comment: I linked that one because it suggests that the char is actually a newline character

Comment: @Scriptable no it is not new line character

Comment: Have you tried with this code: 
phoneNumber.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\p{Cf}", with: "", options: .regularExpression)

Comment: If i check it in a playground it is the â character. and because there is a char after it at the end, trimming that one won't work

Comment: To remove scalar characters with: var newString = ""
for char in phoneNumber.unicodeScalars{
    if char.isASCII{
        newString += String(char)
    }
}

Comment: @BhavikModi Yes it is working but What I need is to encounter all the non ascii characters

Comment: Please show the output of `print(Array(phoneNumber!.unicodeScalars))` to clarify what character really is in your string.

Comment: @MartinR it is `["\u{202D}", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "\u{202C}", "0"]`

Comment: @MartinR Sir Any better way then my answer ?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442008/1187415 to the question to which @Scriptable linked in the first comment solves the problem. And that is actually copied from https://stackoverflow.com/q/47623828/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you :) My question is will it work for all the scenarios like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you every one for your help. You are so kind

I am able to find the invalid character using

`phoneNumber?.map{$0.unicodeScalars.allSatisfy{$0.isASCII}}`

and it returns

```
Optional<Array<Bool>>
  ▿ some : 12 elements
    - 0 : false
    - 1 : true
    - 2 : true
    - 3 : true
    - 4 : true
    - 5 : true
    - 6 : true
    - 7 : true
    - 8 : true
    - 9 : true
    - 10 : false
    - 11 : true
```

I am able to fix this issue using one line

`phoneNumber?.filter{$0.unicodeScalars.allSatisfy{$0.isASCII}}`

and Count is 10

using

`phoneNumber?.filter{$0.unicodeScalars.allSatisfy{$0.isASCII}}.count`

Hope it is helpful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
    var specialCharRemove: String {
       let characters = Set("1234567890+-=().!_")
       return self.filter {characters.contains($0)}
    }
}
```

Use:

```
let str = "12345.!". specialCharRemove
```

Result:

12345